# Linking to specific slide in carousel from array of thumbnails

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a gallery field from ACF in WordPress. I want to output all the images as thumbs (arranged with Masonry), and then if an image is clicked to open a carousel (which is in a modal) and for the carousel to jump to the appropriate slide.

The image thumbs display just as I want them to with this code:

```
<?php $galleryImages = get_field('image_gallery'); 
if ($galleryImages): ?>

<div id="image-gallery" style="margin: auto" class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer", "gutter": 10, "fitWidth": "true" }'>
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <?php $slideNumber = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ( $galleryImages as $image ): ?>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="#carousel-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-slide-to="<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>">
            <img class="gallery" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['medium']; ?>">
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php 
    $slideNumber++;
    endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

And the carousel in a modal is generated perfectly using:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="carousel-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php $class = 'carousel-item active'; ?>
                        <?php foreach ( $galleryImages as $carouselSlide ): ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo $carouselSlide['sizes']['large']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <?php $class = 'carousel-item'; 
                endforeach; ?>
                    </div>

                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

When I click on an image, the carousel opens up and starts scrolling through the images, but it does not open at the image I clicked on, just wherever it happens to be in its sequence. How can I get that to happen?

I have tried adding `data-target="#carousel"` to the `a` around the `img` in `.grid-item` but this did not work; when I clicked on an image the screen just went dark.

UPDATE:
I have used this exact same code on another site and it worked like a charm. My guess is it's a Javascript issue, but I know next to nothing about that so have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of nowhere it came to me:

Replace the `data-slide-to` attribute on the `a` with `onclick="$('.carousel').carousel(<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>)"`. Works as expected.

The previous site was a fluke. It turned out one of the plugins it used was adding some script that made it work.